# Loss Nan: How can I properly implement a LSTM Time-Series model with a lot of parameters?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm, sequence

## The Problem:

I am very new to TF and Keras. I am attempting to train a time-series LSTM. When using only a few parameters as a test, the model seems to work fine. Once I increase the parameters to the full 17010, I almost instantly receive a `loss: nan`.

## Network Specs:

My inputs have been normalized into a range between 0 and 1 and almost all look fairly clean with no significant outliers. When graphing each of the parameters, they look similar to this:

[image]

Some specs on my network:

- Training examples (Time steps): **9835**
- Input parameters: **17010**
- Input sequence length: **30**
- Output parameters: **1**
- Output sequence length: **1**

In summary, the entire sequence of inputs coming from the Timeseries generator end up with shape **(30, 17010, 9835)** I have tried batch sizes between **32** and **256**.

*Note: My inputs have a lot of missing values. Since my model is attempting to predict the increase or decrease as percent change from the previous time step (1 day). ie. `y[i] > 0.5 --> increase` and `y[i] < 0.5 --> decrease`. To fill these missing values I have assigned them a value of `0.5`*

## I Have Tried:

1. Decreasing dropout rate
2. Clipping gradients (don't think this is necessary for me since everything is between 0 and 1)
3. Checked all inputs for NaN or Inf values
4. Increasing batch size
5. Decreasing my learning rate
6. Reducing number of input parameters to **3406**

I have found conflicting information on the number of layers and units that are appropriate but I have attempted to play with these values a little bit. I have tried between **32** and **2000** hidden units.

## My Code:

I am using a `keras.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator` for both training and validation like this:

```py
dataset_train = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
    x_train,
    y_train,
    length=past,
    batch_size=batch_size,
)
```

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences=False, activation='relu', input_shape=(past, dataset_train.data.shape[1])))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(hidden_units))
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate), loss="mse")

path_checkpoint = "model_checkpoint.h5"
es_callback = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0, patience=5)
model.summary()
modelckpt_callback = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    monitor="val_loss",
    filepath=path_checkpoint,
    verbose=1,
    save_weights_only=True,
    save_best_only=True,
)

history = model.fit(
    dataset_train,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=dataset_val,
    callbacks=[es_callback, modelckpt_callback, PlotLossesKeras()],
)
```

I'm not sure if this many parameters are near impossible to train with since I have a smaller number of examples or if something else is causing this. I appreciate any advice you can give me.